# Can a React App run on AWS S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I am creating a React App that doesn't have a database connection for the moment, am just trying to get the frontend UI working before I get the database up. I have been trying to host the application on AWS S3 as a static website but not having much luck. I have linked up the React CDN to an index.html page but when I run it nothing seems to be rendering.

Question is, is it even possible to have a React App running on S3? Or do I need to have a Node server running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, hosting a react app on S3 is possible. All you need to do is create a build of your project and upload those files on s3 as a static website.

The build just creates a bundle of all your js files and dependency which can just be hosted. I found a great detailed article on how you can setup s3 and build and deploy your react app.

Ref: [[https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/deploying-a-react-app-to-s3/]](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/deploying-a-react-app-to-s3/)